# SmartTabLayout Ripple Effect on click

Tags: android, tabs, material-design, android-tablayout, ripple

I'm using [SmartTabLayout](https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout/) and i want to disable **ripple effect** and some gray square background when i click or select a tab.

I added this code to my xml but still didn't work:

```
app:tabBackground="?attr/transparentColor"
android:background="?attr/transparentColor"
```

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31605514/tablayout-highlite-and-ripple-effect), but didn't work too.

Any Idea ?
this is my xml:

```
<com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout.SmartTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/viewpagertab"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_height"
    app:tabBackground="@android:color/transparent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    app:stl_indicatorAlwaysInCenter="false"
    app:stl_indicatorWithoutPadding="false"
    app:stl_indicatorInFront="false"
    app:stl_indicatorInterpolation="smart"
    app:stl_indicatorGravity="bottom"
    app:stl_indicatorColor="#40C4FF"
    app:stl_indicatorThickness="2dp"
    app:stl_indicatorWidth="auto"
    app:stl_underlineColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:stl_underlineThickness="1dp"
    app:stl_dividerColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:stl_dividerThickness="1dp"
    app:stl_indicatorCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:stl_defaultTabTextAllCaps="true"
    app:stl_defaultTabTextColor="#FC000000"
    app:stl_defaultTabTextSize="14sp"
    app:stl_defaultTabTextHorizontalPadding="16dp"
    app:stl_defaultTabTextMinWidth="0dp"
    app:stl_distributeEvenly="false"
    app:stl_clickable="true"
    app:stl_titleOffset="24dp"
    app:stl_drawDecorationAfterTab="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried *android:clickable="true"* ?

Comment: i've tried `android:clickable="true"` but didn't work

Comment: if that's the case you may want to report an issue or enhancement to the author of the library.

Comment: yes, i've submitted this issue and waiting for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it with the following code:

```
    //Remove Ripple
    for(int i=0; i < tabIcon.tabs().length; i++)
    {
        View tabs = viewPagerTab.getTabAt(i);
        tabs.setBackground(null);
    }
```